# No aparece QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt

Estoy haciendo un pequeño form con Qt, inserto varios botones QPushButton, pero no tengo que añadir la cabecera que lo especifica, ni se añade nada en los .cpp ni en los .h, pero funciona perfectamente. La librería es incluida dentro de otra? En cuál?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las clases gráficas de Qt se encuentran en la librería [`QtWidgets`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtwidgets-index.html), luego cualquier aplicación de Qt que tenga interfaz gráfica va a incluir esta librería.

¿Cómo se incluye? Busca en el fichero del projecto (`.pro`) y encontrarás algo similar a esto:

```
QT += widgets
```

Esta instrucción le indica a la compilación que debe cargar la librería de widgets de Qt (nota que las librerías que no son de Qt se cargan de forma completamente diferente).

Ahora bien, si yo abro el proyecto con QtCreator, creo un formulario y en el mismo pongo un botón... cuando ejecuto el código aparece el botón sin yo añadir ninguna referencia ¿Cómo es posible?

En Qt los formularios pueden disponer de un fichero `ui` que básicamente es un XML en el que se almacena la composición del formulario. En el momento de compilar la aplicación, `qmake` genera un *MOC* a partir de esa información, que no es más que el código fuente que genera la composición detallada en el `ui`... y casualmente tu clase `Formulario` incluye una referencia a dicho *MOC*. Si revisas el fichero * MOC* (necesitas compilar antes) verás que en dicho fichero se encuentran los includes correspondientes al botón y al resto de elementos gráficos del formulario.

Comment: Entonces no vale con poner solo el #include <QtWidgets>?

Comment: @Jogofus no, y de hecho creo que ese include no es ni tan siquiera válido...

Comment: Entonces, si no es válido, para que son todos los include que genera el propio proyecto, cómo QMainWindow? Pensaba que al ser c++ pero se añadirán las librerías de la misma forma que la std.

Comment: @Jogofus son cosas diferentes... la librería tiene el código fuente todo aglutinado... pero las cabeceras siguen siendo independientes y si no incluyes la cabecera que declara `QPushButton` (directa o indirectamente), no podrás crear o usar objetos de ese tipo

Comment: La cabecera no es el archivo .h?

Comment: Lo digo porque estaba siguiendo una guía y añadían la librería <QPushButton> de forma manual, y hacías hincapié en ello porque decía que si no no funciona...

Comment: @Jogofus Me has entendido mal. Te he dicho que `#include <QtWidgets>` no va a funcionar... yo no he dicho en ningún momento que `#include <QPushButton>`  te vaya a fallar...

Comment: @Jogofus pero para que `#include <QPushButton>` funcione debes cargar en tu proyecto la librería `QtWidgets`, ya que con la cabecera solo no vas a poder hacer gran cosa... necesitas el binario asociado a dicha cabecera y el mismo se encuentra en la librería que te estoy diciendo

Comment: Entonces, si no entiendo mal, cualquier objeto que se cree en la .ui está creado en QtWidgets y se debe referenciar en el archivo .pro. Y si no se hiciera así habria que añadir librería por librería los objetos que vayamos a usar?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76540/discussion-between-eferion-and-jogofus).